# Correct way to write a resource to get states from a country in a RESTful API?

Tags: php, rest, url, architecture, restful-architecture

I'm in doubt which of the two options is correct when listing states from a country.

Group State Collection
[GET]
`/location/states?country={country_id}`

Or

Group Country Collection
[GET]
`/location/country/{id}/states`

Which is the correct way in a well write RESTful API?

Comment: pretty URLs have completely **nothing** to do with REST

Comment: @tereško I agree, but can you explain better about it? My second approach I write to make sense in a first view.... But a good and with more sense URI is .../states?country={country_id}? And /cities?state={state_id}&country={country_id}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain model only exposes *states* as resources and not *countries*, you could go with the first option. You would expose *states* as resources and filter them by their *country*. Also consider if this might ever change, i.e. might *countries* become resources at some point?

If *countries* are considered resources, which means they can be represented by more than just an ID, then I think the second option is the correct choice of the two.

API design is not black and white, so I'd say there is no definite right answer, it depends on context.

Comment: In my business domain an ad about rent a product can be in any city of the world. But, if the user(who searching by this ads) , set in your session that he is in New York (NY) just ads from New York City are returned from your search and if  he set New Jersey, all ads from New Jersey(any city in new Jersey) are return in your search. This example gets cities and states, on the same way of my question gets countries or states.